# I want to implement Oauth From class without using Pages and getting 302 URI MISMATCH ERROR. i HAVE USED THE FOLLOWING cODE

Tags: oauth

```
public class oAuth_Controller{

private auth_response rt;

public pagereference auth_Step_1(){


    String auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize';
    String params =  
                        '?response_type=code' +
                        '&client_id=' + encodingUtil.urlencode('YOURCLIENTID','UTF-8') +
                        '&redirect_uri=https://na1.salesforce.com/apex/{YOURVFPAGE}' +                           '&prompt=consent' + 
                        '&scope=' + encodingUtil.URLEncode('full refresh_token','UTF-8') +
                        '&state=step2';
        pageReference pr = New PageReference(auth_url + params);
        return pr;
}

public pagereference auth_Step_2(){

    if(apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('state') != 'step2')
        return null;


    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();

    String auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String params =  
                        '?code=' + apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('code') +
                        '&grant_type=authorization_code' + 
                        '&client_id=' + encodingUtil.urlencode('YOURCLIENTID','UTF-8') +
                        '&client_secret=YOURSECRET' + 
                        '&redirect_uri=https://ap1.salesforce.com/apex/YOURVFPAGENAME';

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(auth_url + params);

    HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);

    rt = (auth_response)json.deserialize(resp.getBody(),auth_response.class);
    //Do something with the results
    return null;

}

public void getnewtoken(){

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();

    String auth_url = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
    String params =  

                        '?grant_type=refresh_token' + 
                        '&client_id=' + encodingUtil.urlencode('YOURCLIENTID','UTF-8') +
                        '&client_secret=YOURSECRET' + 
                        '&refresh_token=' + encodingUtil.URLEncode(YOURREFRESHTOKEN,'UTF-8');

    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(auth_url + params);

    HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req);


}



private class auth_response{

    public string refresh_token;
    public string access_token;

}
}
```

Comment: My problem is i have to use this in schedule class. For that i tried this code HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); Http http = new Http(); req.setMethod('GET'); req.setEndpoint(auth_url + params); HTTPResponse resp = http.send(req); but i am getting 302 error

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection.

An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the location header field. The user agent (e.g. a web browser) is invited by a response with this code to make a second, otherwise identical, request to the new URL specified in the location field. The HTTP/1.0 specification (RFC 1945) initially defined this code, and gives it the description phrase "Moved Temporarily".

Many web browsers implemented this code in a manner that violated this standard, changing the request type of the new request to GET, regardless of the type employed in the original request (e.g. POST). For this reason, HTTP/1.1 (RFC 2616) added the new status codes 303 and 307 to disambiguate between the two behaviours, with 303 mandating the change of request type to GET, and 307 preserving the request type as originally sent. Despite the greater clarity provided by this disambiguation, the 302 code is still employed in web frameworks to preserve compatibility with browsers that do not implement the HTTP/1.1 specification.

As a consequence, the update of RFC 2616 changes the definition to allow user agents to rewrite POST to GET.

Here is explained it in details http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E302.html I think you need to find another solution or way to your task.